# regarding the correct way to call a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose there is a function defined as

```
def function1(x, y, z=True,a):
     ...
     ...
```

When I call function1, it seems I can call the function in the following manners

```
function1(10,2,3)

function1(x=10,y=2,a=3)
```

But calling `function1(x=10,y=2, 3)` will cause error, where `3` should be assigned to `a`. Generally, what are the correct ways to call a function withou causing potential issues.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a valid way to define a function in python 2 or 3. Default arguments (ones with default values, namely `x=y`) must come after non-default arguments. With your function definition, you should receive the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean that, for the function defined in the above, I have to call it as function1(x=10,y=2,3,z=True). since z has default value in the function setup. Even I want use z's default value, I still need to explicit write it down when calling the function. Is that right?

Comment: No, I mean that you cannot *define* the function that way. Your example is invalid, the default arguments *in the function definition* need to come after the other ones.